# absolute positioned element clipping if position outside its parent item IE7

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6

**Hi**

Im trying to position an element so its slightly positioned outside its parent item. In IE8 it works but in IE7 the positioned element gets clipped.

Here's my code HTML:

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="child">text</div>
</div>
```

The CSS

```
#parent {
height: 40px;
width: 400px;
position: relative;
}

#child {
position: absolute;
width: 100px;
height: 60px;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
}
```

In IE7 you will see that the last 20px of the child element gets clipped. 
How can I solve this?

**THX**

Comment: Do you have a live example? Here's one http://jsfiddle.net/PCg6m/

Comment: awesome! When I brokedown my original code I thought it wouldn't work but apperantly it does. Now I know its not a bug so I'll have to review my code again. Hopefully I can close this issue.

Comment: now I found the problem. If its I have an sibling to the parent element that has is position relative assigned to it.
http://jsfiddle.net/DrhBE/

Comment: I found it. I just put a z-index to the relative positioned elements and it seems to work. Got to say that is a first. I've never before set a z-index to a relative positioned element. Lovely IE!

Comment: Well `z-index` only works on positioned elements, but I'm glad you found the problem.

Comment: If this is the solution to your problem, please add it as a solution and accept it.

Answer (score 4):

Its just the famous [z-index bug](http://benhollis.net/experiments/ie7_tests/zindex.html) for IE7 
The problem with IE7 is that it applies z-index=0 for all the positioned elements 
 i.e elements with position != static has z-index=0.
So eventually this [stacking context](http://css-discuss.incutio.com/wiki/Overlapping_And_ZIndex) that causes the issue