# Child elements clipped when rotating parent in IE 7/8

Tags: html, css

Clipping issue in IE 7/8.

If I rotate a parent div, the image inside of it gets clipped even though overflow is not set to hidden. The image appears fine when there's no rotation but once it's transformed at all, anything outside the bounds of the parent are hidden.

Screenshot in IE7:
http://c311725.r25.cf1.rackcdn.com/Screen%20Shot%202012-08-24%20at%2010.38.21%20AM.png

Making the parent div larger obviously fixes the issue here but that won't work well with the actual site I'm trying to apply this fix to. Thanks for any tips!

http://jsfiddle.net/56SS9/

Answer (score 0):

I believe it has to do with the z-index in ie 7 being weird. Try setting the z index of the image higher than its rotating parent. I haven't run into it first hand so I'm not sure what/if there is a solution.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2880363/absolute-positioned-element-clipping-if-position-outside-its-parent-item-ie7) for a previously asked, similar question, which didn't provide a clear solution.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! It seems like the issue here is the rotation which that other post doesn't address at all. I tried adding in some z-indexes for the heck of it and no luck.

Comment: No, not directly it doesn't mention rotation, but it has to do with a child element being positioned slightly outside of the parent element, which is what is happening when you rotate. If the z-indexes don't work, you may be SOL. Horrah for old IE!

Comment: Yeah, no luck after messing around with it more. Thanks for trying to help.